# List returns empty even when path is correct for screen scraper

Tags: python, screen-scraping

So im trying to get all the url from the free games site on Ubisoft website however it keeps returning empty. I dont know what I'm doing wrong here, image below shows the path

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0",
}

result = requests.get("https://free.ubisoft.com/", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')
print(result.content)
urls = []
urls = soup.find('div', {'class': 'free-events'}).find_all("a")
for url in urls:

    link = url.attrs['data-url']
    if "https" in link:
        links.append(link)

return links
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is loaded dynamically so if you print the `result.content` you see that there is only some simple HTML and Javascript.

Using Selenium you can load the page and retrieve the links like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get("https://free.ubisoft.com/")
for link in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.free-event-button a[data-type='freegame']"):
    print(link.get_attribute("data-url"))

# https://register.ubisoft.com/aco-discovery-tour
# https://register.ubisoft.com/acod-discovery-tour
# https://register.ubisoft.com/might_and_magic_chess_royale
# https://register.ubisoft.com/rabbids-coding
```

Comment: how do I stop it opening chrome when I run the code?

Comment: Use `headless` when you start the browser, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The content is loaded dynamically via JavaScript, but you can simulate Javascript requests with `requests` module.

For example:

```
import re
import requests

configuration_url = 'https://free.ubisoft.com/configuration.js'
configuration_js = requests.get(configuration_url).text

app_id = re.search(r"appId:\s*'(.*?)'",configuration_js).group(1)
url = re.search(r"prod:\s*'(.*?)'",configuration_js).group(1)

data = requests.get(url, headers={'ubi-appid': app_id,'ubi-localecode': 'en-US'}).json()

# pretty print all data:
import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "news": [
        {
            "spaceId": "6d0af36b-8226-44b6-a03b-4660073a6349",
            "newsId": "ignt.21387",
            "type": "freegame",
            "placement": "freeevents",
            "priority": 1,
            "displayTime": 0,
            "publicationDate": "2020-05-14T17:01:00",
            "expirationDate": "2020-05-21T18:01:00",
            "title": "Assassin's Creed Origins Discovery Tour",
            "body": "Assassin's Creed Origins Discovery Tour",
            "mediaURL": "https://ubistatic2-a.akamaihd.net/sitegen/assets/img/ac-odyssey/ACO_DiscoveryTour_logo.png",
            "mediaType": null,
            "profileId": null,
            "obj": {},
            "links": [
                {
                    "type": "External",
                    "param": "https://register.ubisoft.com/aco-discovery-tour",
                    "actionName": "goto"
                }
            ],
            "locale": "en-US",
            "tags": null
        },

... and so on.
```

EDIT: To iterate over this data, you can use this example:

```
import re
import requests

configuration_url = 'https://free.ubisoft.com/configuration.js'
configuration_js = requests.get(configuration_url).text

app_id = re.search(r"appId:\s*'(.*?)'",configuration_js).group(1)
url = re.search(r"prod:\s*'(.*?)'",configuration_js).group(1)

data = requests.get(url, headers={'ubi-appid': app_id,'ubi-localecode': 'en-US'}).json()

for no, news in enumerate(data['news'], 1):
    print('{:<5}{:<45}{}'.format(no, news['title'], news['links'][0]['param']))
```

Prints:

```
1    Assassin's Creed Origins Discovery Tour      https://register.ubisoft.com/aco-discovery-tour
2    Assassin's Creed Odyssey Discovery Tour      https://register.ubisoft.com/acod-discovery-tour
3    Uno Demo                                     https://register.ubisoft.com/uno-trial
4    The Division 2 Trial                         https://register.ubisoft.com/the-division-2-trial
5    Ghost Recon Breakpoint Trial                 https://register.ubisoft.com/ghost-recon-breakpoint-trial
6    Might and Magic Chess Royale                 https://register.ubisoft.com/might_and_magic_chess_royale
7    Rabbids Coding                               https://register.ubisoft.com/rabbids-coding
8    Trials Rising Demo                           https://register.ubisoft.com/trials-rising-demo
9    The Crew 2 Trial                             https://register.ubisoft.com/tc2-trial
10   Ghost Recon Wildlands Trial                  https://register.ubisoft.com/ghost-recon-wildlands-trial
11   The Division Trial                           https://register.ubisoft.com/the-division-trial
```

EDIT 2: To filter only free games, you can do:

```
no = 1
for news in data['news']:
    if news['type'] != 'freegame':
        continue
    print('{:<5}{:<45}{}'.format(no, news['title'], news['links'][0]['param']))
    no += 1
```

Prints:

```
1    Assassin's Creed Origins Discovery Tour      https://register.ubisoft.com/aco-discovery-tour
2    Assassin's Creed Odyssey Discovery Tour      https://register.ubisoft.com/acod-discovery-tour
3    Might and Magic Chess Royale                 https://register.ubisoft.com/might_and_magic_chess_royale
4    Rabbids Coding                               https://register.ubisoft.com/rabbids-coding
```

Comment: how can I loop through the json data based on how many games there are? Right now there are 4 games, how do I make sure it can get them all even if there are 5 games

Comment: @DawidOlejnik I added an example how to iterate over the data to my answer.

Comment: Is there any way to filter out the trails. so that only full games show up i.e Assassin's Creed Origins Discovery Tour ,Assassin's Creed Odyssey Discovery Tour,Might and Magic Chess Royale  ,Rabbids Coding